# Is a specific setting needed to make the "is "keyword work in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}


interface Tabacudo{
  name:string,
  nickName:string
}



function isUser(o: any) : o is User {
    //by using the type predicate: "o is User"
    //o should be cast to Use as the example on this source:
    // "https://languageimperfect.com/2019/08/05/understanding-typescript-type-predicates.html"
    const u: User = o 
    return typeof u.id  === "number"
        && typeof u.name === "string"
        && typeof u.foo === "string"
        && typeof u.bar === "string";
}

let o : any = {};
if(isUser(o)) {
    console.log(o.id); // o is User 
}
```

the return statment within isUser returns false

and if I switch "function isUser(o: any) : o is User" to "function isUser(o: any) : o is Tabacudo" not even a warning is begeted.

is there any special version of typescript to make the "is" keyword to work??

Comment: `is` is working as intended... **You** decide what the type predicate is. TypeScript does not check if your runtime validation matches your type predicate.

Comment: Type predicates dont validate *your validation* at all. All they do is require the function to return a boolean. You can also just return `true` and there will be no error.

Comment: @all, are you saying this: "let o : any = {};" is the mistake I made? and instead I should have done this: "let o : User = {id:2, name:'john snow', foo:'some', bar: 'thing'};???? if that is so then using "o is User" as function return type seems irrelevant, right?

Comment: I don't see much of a mistake in the actual formatted code except that you haven't checked that `o` is an object inside your custom type guard.  If you changed the return type to `o is Tabacudo` then that would be a mistake, but... you didn't make that mistake in your example, so... I'm confused.  What "mistake" are you talking about?  Could you [edit] the code in the question to show exactly where you are expecting something different to happen and what that difference is?

Comment: *Maybe* you're saying that you want the compiler to validate that you've written your type guard function correctly, and if so, then this is essentially too complex as per [ms/TS#29980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29980), and not the intended purpose of such functions. Type predicate functions were introduced to the language in order to allow developers to get narrowings on their own terms; sort of like conditional [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that assert depending on a condition.

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for your reply. well I expected since isUser function return type is o is User, typescript made a cast from object o to User regardless this line of code: let o : any = {}; get it? so o inside isUser function would be casted to the User interface, get it? I even reinforced that by writing: const u: User = o

Comment: Either I don't understand what you're saying, or you don't understand what [custom type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) are supposed to be, or both.  What do you mean by "cast"ing? It's an ambiguous term.  If you mean some sort of runtime type coercion, then this never happens in TypeScript.  What are you *trying* to do with the code?

Comment: @jcalz, by casting I meant the object o(let o: any = {}) which is of type any be converted to type User interface(o:User), get it? at least I thoght that was what the "is" keyword in typescript was for otherwise I see no functional use for "is" in typescipt other than just being semantic

Comment: Maybe you don't understand about [type erasure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types)? The entirety of the static type system is just "semantic". Anyway, I think we have reached the end of what we can meaningfully discuss.  I recommend that you [edit] the question to be very explicit and clear about what you expect to happen where. If you do this and want me to take another look, you can mention @jcalz in a comment. If you don't feel like doing this then it's not necessary to contact me directly again.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz, I've added some comment within isUser function that I hope expline better what I belive that shoul be happening to o object.

Comment: `o` ***is*** "cast" to User inside the `if` block. It's still unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to understand your problem. You've written a type guard function and are unhappy with *something* about it, but it's not clear.  You use the word "cast", which is, unfortunately, *ambiguous*, and should be replaced with something else.  I'm very sorry; I would love to help, but I think I'm done with this question.  Hopefully someone else understands what you want and can provide assistance.

Comment: @jcalz, do you know java? it would be cast like the one java works with, but maybe in this case I could change cast with conversion. Would that be helpful?

Comment: But you don't *need* to cast. The type guard has basically done this for you...